# Grab Query, drop in $_Session

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

Trying to get the value I'm setting at the end for $_SESSION to be the user_id from the query, and not $username.  I can't seem to work my way around modifying the query.  I'm sure this is crazy easy for some of the gurus here.

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
    $sel_user = "select user_id, user_first_name from users where username='$username' AND password='$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

    if($check_user>0){
        $_SESSION['session_id']=$username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the row from the query results:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user);
```

Then you get the `user_id` from there:

```
if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['session_id'] = $row['user_id'];
}
```

You don't need to call `mysqli_num_rows()`. If there were no matches, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following snippet:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

        $selUserQuery = 'select user_id from users where username = "' . $username . '" and password = "' . $password . '"';

        if( $selUserStmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $selUserQuery) )
        {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($selUserStmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selUserStmt, $userId);

            while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that I have changed your `$_SESSION['session_id']` into `$_SESSION['user_id']`, hoping to reduce confusion for future readers.